# Как пробросить Nginx в WSL на директорию вне WSL?

Tags: nginx, wsl

Установил Nginx на WSL и теперь папка с Ubuntu 18.04 доступна по адресу

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows\LocalState\rootfs
```

Мой проект локальной разработки находится в `D:/github/project/`

Указание директивы `root D:/github/example.com/public;` не работает. Можно ли вообще в таком режиме работы пробросить запросы к папке на другом диске или вне WSL вообще?

Comment: `/mnt/d` ?. . .

Comment: @andreymal сработало, спасибо